# java dialog box is not working after writing this code

Tags: java

I was working on java by writing a try and catch code. I wrote in the first number 5 for instance and in the second 0 and it's an error so it will jump on catch, but in catch statement I wrote dialog box
but it's not working on this code, but in any code it runs. I tried a lot in finding the problem. This is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        java.util.Scanner s = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter number 1 :");
        int num1 = s.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter number 2 :");
        int num2 = s.nextInt();
        int cal = num1 / num2;

    } catch(Exception x){
        javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "something Wrong happend");
    }
}
```

The question here why dialog box is not working and why it stopped at this dialog box?

Comment: what do you mean by `why dialog box is not working and why it stopped at this dialog box?` I checked your code and its working correctly after division by zero its catching the error and showing the dialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dialog box is working. It is probably hidden behind another window. Try to iterate through all your windows until you find it. Until you find it and close it, your program will be stuck. It will not continue executing until you close the `JOptionPane`.

For what it's worth, although using a `JOptionPane` in a java console program works, it is not a good idea, in my opinion, since `JOptionPane` was not intended to be used in a java console program.